# Use Apache virtual hosts to access local servers?

Tags: apache, networking

I was wondering if it's possible to use Apache to request websites on a local network, with apache being the gateway so to speak? On my home network I currently have a Windows box running an ASP.NET site, it has to run under Windows/IIS, a server I'm not particularly fond of, but I can live with it... Alongside this I'm thinking about running an Apache server on a separate machine, for my PHP applications, as well as some other applications (e.g. Plex).o

Ideally I'd like to have Apache on port 80, listening for requests, and using the sort of functionality I have with a virtual hosts file to load content from another webserver on my network, that isn't directly accessible through it's own port. I know I could just run PHP under IIS, or move one server to another port, but there's no fun in that!